# About Java Garbage Collection Times

Tags: java, garbage-collection

There are totalms tags in the GC log file. like This totalms="369.415" I want to know is the time CPU time or Physics time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [About Java Garbage Collection Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463320/about-java-garbage-collection-time)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again within 45 minutes? Edit and improve the previous question if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what I found.

The warning message clock error detected in time totalms indicates that when verbosegc sampled the `system time` at the end of the garbage collection.

Found it in below link.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.60%2Fdiag%2Ftools%2Fgcpd_timing.html

+1 for the Question.